Using ltmarks for counter ranges in headers
The latest kernel releases have been advertising the generalization and enhancement of the LaTeX marks mechanism at the ltmarks module. So I've trying to play with it a little (with a use particular use case I have in mind).
Now, I'm not well acquainted with either the details of the output routine or the technicalities of the mark mechanism. I just know the traditional user level \markboth and \markright. And -- spoiler alert -- this question will probably boil down to that.
In my actual use case, my attempts have been sensitive to the placement of \mark_insert:nn, but in trying to create a MWE, it seems I'm really failing to understand how things were supposed to work on a more fundamental level.
Consider the following document, which I'd expect to work:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter}aa] \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}{Foo: \FirstMark{mymarks}--\LastMark{mymarks}}

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}

But it does not work at all. I'd expect it to print the range of the items which started on a given page. But in practice we get empty ranges "Foo: –" for every page.
Now, with \DebugMarksOn we get some info in the log. And the marks seem to be being set. We see things like:
Marks: set mymarks <- '\__mark_id:n {10}5' on line 26
Marks: set mymarks <- '\__mark_id:n {11}6' on line 26

and so on, and consistently so.
However, in the OR, these sets seem not to be visible at all. So we see for every page something like:
Marks: mymarks in OR (twoside-even):
    page (current):|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|
    page (previous):|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|
    column (previous):|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|
    column (current):|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|
    column (first):|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|
    column (second):|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|\__mark_id:n {0}|

Even if I replace \InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} with some static information, like \InsertMark{mymarks}{bar}, it doesn't seem to get to the point I'm trying to access the information at all.
What am I missing?

I think I got what seemed to be baffling me: \InsertMark is documented to have "no effect in places in which you can’t place floats, e.g., a mark inside a box or inside a footnote never shows up anywhere".
And the \item's label is first typeset as a box, which seems to be the source of the problem in the MWE. Indeed, with:
\item[aa]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]

the document produces expected results.
Also, the same issue appears to be the source of the "sensitivity to the placement of \mark_insert:nn" in my actual use case. So, I guess I'm back on my feet enough to play some more.

Yes marks work in the same places footnotes work, you similarly can't have a page footnote from inside a box

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for confirming. I didn't even remember the item label was set in a box to start with, it was just the natural place to put in my actual use case. So I guess this question was just a "debugging exercise". ;-)

@DavidCarlisle Do you happen to know anyone using the "generalize aspect" of the new mark mechanism? Some grepping in my TeXLive tree for new mark classes produced no results.
